# How to close suspicious port 999 garcon, is it malware?

Tags: macos, security, port, nmap

On Mac OSX, I ran the command
`nmap localhost`
and I found I have this suspicious open port:

> 999/tcp   open  garcon

Then I tried to see if there is an associated process, but nothing shows up with
`lsof -i | grep 999`.

Two questions:

- Does any body know if this is could be a key-logger/trojan?
- How can I close the port?

[Edit]
The right command is

**sudo lsof -i :999**

and then I can see the process

> rpc.rquot 704 root 6u  IPv4 0xc899fa4ad7097125      0t0  TCP *:garcon (LISTEN)

Now after reading http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpc.rquotad
I suspect that maybe is a port open by fuse4x, or fuse4x-kext

Comment: Malware can use any name it wants, however there is at least one program named garcon which is **not** malware.

Cat  /var/db/pkg/garcon-0.2.1/+DESC
Garcon is an implementation of the freedesktop.org menu specification
replacing the former Xfce menu library libxfce4menu. It is based on
GLib/GIO only and aims at covering the entire specification except for
legacy menus.

WWW: http://www.xfce.org/

Answer (score 1):

The name you see actually comes from /etc/services file which maps port numbers to well-known service names.

glad the lsof command worked.